# My IF statement is not working using SQL Server data

Tags: java, sql-server, if-statement, netbeans

I'm having a problem with my statements (I'm guessing). I'm doing a small web app that needs to have a login form. I created the form in the index.jsp page, and when I submit it (having my username and password fields filled) it actions a "login.jsp".

This is my login.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String fUser = request.getParameter("l_user");
        String fPass = request.getParameter("l_pass");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://GrayFox-PC:1433;databaseName=AO2AYDAW", "usuario", "123");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Usuario='"+fUser+"' AND Pass='"+fPass+"'");

            while (rs.next()) { 
                if (fUser.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Usuario")) && fPass.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Pass"))) {
                    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
                } else {
                    out.print("Usuario Invalido");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            out.print("Error en la conexión. - " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a snippet of the form from the index.jsp:

```
<form method="POST" action="login.jsp" class="pure-form">
                <b>Usuario:</b> <input name="l_user" type="text" size="15">
                <b>Contraseña:</b> <input name="l_pass" type="password" size="15">
                <input type="submit" value="Ingresar">
</form>
```

The thing is, I'm pretty sure I filled the form with the right data I have in my database table.

And for some reason it just executes the "else" state, the "if" seems to not be working, I tried using the `.equals` with my strings, but nothing. Maybe the `&&` is not working as it should, or I am doing something wrong, but I'm not able to figure it right now.

Comment: Add some logging and print the variables `fUser`, `fPass` to check what's going on

Comment: I already did that, I printed them and I have the desired values. Thanks

Comment: So debug the stuff and check which part of the `if` does not what you expected. As you use NetBeans: mark one part of the `if` and move the cursor over the selection while debugging.

Comment: I'm not really good using the debugging tool, but I think there is nothing strange, maybe I'm not looking on the right window or lines. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
String sql = ""SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Usuario='"+fUser+"' AND Pass='"+fPass+"'"";
System.out.println("sql: " + sql); //check that in a sql-tool against your db if it works as expected.
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) { 
    System.out.println("fUser: " + fUser);
    System.out.println("fPass: " + fPass);
    System.out.println("usuario: " + rs.getString("Usuario"));
    System.out.println("pass: " + rs.getString("Pass"));
    System.out.println("check #1: " + fUser.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Usuario")));
    System.out.println("check #2: " + fPass.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Pass")));

    if (fUser.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Usuario")) && fPass.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getString("Pass"))) {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    } else {
        out.print("Usuario Invalido");
    }
}
System.out.println("end of while");
```

Also you should learn how to use the debugger. Mark the line you want to run to, press Ctrl+F8 to set a breakpoint, start the debugger with Ctrl-F5, step through you app with F8. Everything is made easy.

Comment: Hey thanks for the asnwer. Yeah, it's weird, I tested this code you gave me and it finds the checks as "False"'s. here's what I got: `sql: SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Usuario='Admin' AND Pass='admin' fUser: Admin fPass: admin usuario: Admin pass: admin check #1: false check #2: false Usuario Invalidoend of while ` And yeah it keeps going on the ELSE, obviously, because the boolean in the if are FALSE. Maybe its the database.

Comment: and here I attach a screenshot of the database's table results:
http://imgur.com/LsGG5vI

Comment: hmpf. Debugging would really help... maybe the database also returns trailing spaces. I would recommend to add 'trim ()' to the if, ie. fUser.trim ().equalsIgnoreCase (...). This could be the case when the column type has a fixed length. Add that to the code and the logging  and post the result here.

Comment: That didn't work. But I just solved it, I think I'm stupid, I was using data type CHAR in the table. I dropped the table, created the same, but with VARCHAR type data, and it worked good with my current code. Thanks for your time Chris!

Comment: As far as i know CHAR returns the whole length of the field filled up with spaces at the end. VARCHAR doesn't do that. I wish you success with your project.